# Avoid overlapping of width with whitespace: pre

Tags: css

Hello I am trying to create a conversation like app. I needed `white-space: pre;` to show newlines for my message with \n but when I do.. It will overlap. I am trying to find a way how to make my `\n` create new lines and at the same time create word breaks so the words will not overlap on my div

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p.c {
  white-space: pre;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>white-space: pre:</h2>
<div style="width:300px; background: red">
<p class="c">
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. \n
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
p.c {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

> **pre-wrap:**
>       Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

More about `white-space` values [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

Comment: `pre-line` solved my problem.. What's the difference between pre-wrap and pre-line?

Comment: for pre-wrap `Sequences of white space are preserved`, for pre-line `Sequences of white space are collapsed`.

Comment: So pre-wrap is better?

Comment: pre-wrap will act more like regular html code, for pre-line.... you can imagine all white spaces to be converted into `&nbsp;`, so whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

I should have used pre-line in the first-place to solve it

```
p.c {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```